# How to pass data to jinja templet

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, jinja2

I might be tired after long hours of punching on keyboard but I'm currently unable to move any further.
Here is the code:

```
        elif request.form["submit"] == "blah":
        cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM "Table_x"''')
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        for record in cursor:
            results.append(record)
        return "Showing all:" + str(results) + render_template("index.html")
```

Based on the above, output on rendered template gives me a nasty looking list of tuples.

```
[(1, 'Dummy1', 'dummy1', 1), (2, 'Dummy2', 'dummy2', 2), (3, 'Dummy3', 'dummy3', 3)]
```

How can I change return or results variable (or both) so that each tuple in the list would print in separate line ?

Comment: You need to loop over the list of tuples in jinja, and add a line break (`<br>`) after each tuple.

Comment: Your issue looks like it lies in how you render the template. There's nothing wrong technically in how you're creating the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you are passing the data to your template, using [render_template](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.render_template) from the documentation:

> Renders a template from the template folder with the given context.
>
> Parameters:    template_name_or_list – the name of the template to be
>   rendered, or an iterable with template names the first one existing
>   will be rendered context – the variables that should be available in
>   the context of the template.

The `context` is nothing more than the variables you want to pass as keywords arguments. Follow an example, first the python file `app.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/tuple")
def jpg_to_pdf():
    results = [(1, 'Dummy1', 'dummy1', 1), (2, 'Dummy2', 'dummy2', 2), (3, 'Dummy3', 'dummy3', 3)]
    return render_template('index.html', data=results)
```

and the Jinja template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tuple</title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%">
{% for element in data %}
 <tr>
    <th>{{ element[0] }}</th>
    <th>{{ element[1] }}</th>
    <th>{{ element[2] }}</th>
    <th>{{ element[3] }}</th>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Those files combined render the following `html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tuple</title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%">

 <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>Dummy1</th>
    <th>dummy1</th>
    <th>1</th>
  </tr>

 <tr>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>Dummy2</th>
    <th>dummy2</th>
    <th>2</th>
  </tr>

 <tr>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>Dummy3</th>
    <th>dummy3</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find more about rendering templates [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#rendering-templates).